# Back screen button working in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a view controller on which i have a mapview. Above the mapview there is a back button on which when click it should move back to view controller. But when i hit back button it does not go to the back screen. My code is this in view didLoad,

```
 UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 20, 30,30)];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popVC) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:backButton];
- (void) popVC{
HomeViewController *presales = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:presales animated:YES];
```

}

the button is like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7c2g.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move back to `HomeViewController`

If you use `pushViewController` to show current view controller. You have to use `popViewControllerAnimated` instead of `pushViewController`. Try replace your `popVC` with my code below.

```
- (void) popVC{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If you use `presentViewController` to show current view controller. You have to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` instead of `pushViewController`. Try replace your `popVC` with my code below.

```
- (void) popVC{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: @siddle can you show the code which is used to show current view controller?

Comment: @siddle i have updated my answer with second option. You can check an try again

Comment: it is given above , it is as it written above in question. @trungduc

Comment: Seem like you understood. Welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
By Writing the First Line you get the Indexes of all View Controllers and from second Line You will reach up to your Destination.

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Bro it is not catching this i have NSLog above it the log message is coming but this code is not working. @Faysal Ahmed

Comment: @siddle please check self.navigationController is exist or not.
if self.navigationController object does not exist then popViewController not working.